# Django show page of user favourites

Tags: python, django

I want to create a page where the user can see his favorite posts. How can I modify the following template to show the use favorite post ?

```
{% if (user has any favorite posts %}
    show here
{% else %}
            User has no favorite posts
{% end if %}
        </tr>
```

Here is the **.html** file

```
<td>
    <form method='POST' action="{% url 'foobar:favourite_post' video.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden'>
        <button type='submit'>Bookmark</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Here is the **view.py** file

```
def favourite_post(request, fav_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=fav_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video.favourite.add(request.user)

    return redirect('/foobar/%s' % fav_id)
```

Here is the **models.py** file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    videofile = models.FileField(upload_to="static/videos/"),
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectUser, related_name="fav_videos", blank=True)
```

Comment: `user.fav_videos.exists()` and `for video in user.fav_videos.all()` ? in the template without the brackets

Comment: @BearBrown So I did this  `{% for video in user.fav_videos.all %}
        {% if user.fav_videos.exists %}
            <td>{{ __ }}</td>

            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">No Bookmarked Videos</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`
How can I parse the contents of model and print the name ?

Comment: @BearBrown please let me know if I can provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like all you need is [for-empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)

```
{% for video in user.fav_videos.all %}
    <td>{{ video.name }}</td>
{% empty %}
    <td >No Bookmarked Videos</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Side quesiton as I can see in your bio that you have been doing Django since 2013 :D. Although I have extended the `model` for the `user` to `ProjectUser`, It seems like I can still access it using `user` instead of `ProjectUser`. I though that `user` no longer exists, and everything should accessbile only through `project user` or do I have a misconception here.
>

Comment: if you set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the settings https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-user-model as your class ProjectUser, the only ProjectUser should work, if i correct understand yuor secod question.

Comment: I have this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts_app.ProjectUser'` in my settings

Comment: i think the only `ProjectUser` is your auth model and the `auth_user` table should not exists at all.

Comment: here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438245/extending-user-models-in-django-saves-password-publicly