# Extending user models in Django saves password publicly

Tags: python, django

The password for newly created users is shown publicly on the admin console models. Why is that and how I do it correctly?

Furthermore, I am not actually able to login with any of the new users created in the **Accounts_app**. I am able to login only with the `python manage.py createsuperuser`
I created at the early point in the project.

[image]

Here is the **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here is the **settings.py**

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts_app.ProjectUser'
```

Here is my admin view

[image]

To create the user, I click "Add User" in the app admin view.

[image]

Here is the **apps.py** file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts_app'
```

Here is the **admin.py** file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts_app.models import ProjectUser

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(ProjectUser)
```

Comment: How did you create the userv and set the password?

Comment: when you speak about the `user.id` instead of `projectuser.id` do you mean the attribute of the `request` show pleas your admin view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean the userv ? Can you please tell me what it is so I can get it for you

Comment: @BearBrown yes, I mean the attribute of the request. I updated it with the view of the admin

Comment: Typo. How did you create the user in the first place? How did you set the password for that user?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I created the user using the admin view and set the password there. Furthermore, I am not able to login with any of the users I create in the admin view. I am only able to login with the users I created using the `createsuperuser`.  I updated the question with several screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you set ProjectUser to be the AUTH_USER_MODEL, you registered it in the admin as a standard model, not the user one. You need to use the user admin, as shown in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project), since this takes care of hashing the password:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(ProjectUser, UserAdmin)
```

You'll need to delete and recreate the users you generated via the admin before changing this.

Comment: another side question if you may. To access the `attribute` of `request`, which one do I use`user.id` or `projectuser.id` ?

Comment: Only `user` would work. The Auth middleware sets the `user` attribute to the instance corresponding to the logged in user, no matter what the name of the model is.

Comment: on the link provided it mentions `...including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets....` but the ProjectUser admin view is missing the reset password field, any advise on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, what do you want to do, extend or custom the User Model?

- If you want to extend... It's enough with a foreign key. For this, the Django project recommends using `OneToOneField(User)`

  In this case, see the link below.

  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
- In the other hand, if you want to custom the User model, you must have to do this before doing the migrations. The initial setup must have your customization. You can create an app only for the User Model customization.

  In this case, see the links below.

  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

  https://wsvincent.com/django-tips-custom-user-model/

I hope this helped you